# how to solve import error no module name cv in python?

Tags: opencv

i am running the python code but every time is showing

line 13,in 
     import cv2.cv as cv2

importerror: No module named cv

how to slove this problem,
i am using rPi 2 opencv-3.1.0 with python 2.7

Answer (score 1):

If you have compiled opencv from source, link `cv2.so` from compiled directory to your python system directory (generally it is `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`)

If not helpful, setup `venv` in your project directory and link `cv2.so` and `cv.py` from python system directory to your project directory.